# Can't convert to collection in kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors, kotlin

I'm trying to convert List to LinkedList in kotlin, here is my code with error from intellij

[image: Intellij saying that this won't do]

But in Kotlin REPL i can do something like this

[image: But this is perfectly normal]

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: pls post your code as text (+ error message) not as screenshot. other people cannot search for text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `else` branch, you don't return anything, meaning you return the `Unit` singleton. 
`Unit` is not a subtype of `Token`. Therefore, the Kotlin compiler takes `Unit` and `Token` shared parent class: `Any` (Kotlin's base class, Like `Object` in Java).

Instead of returning `Unit`, you should throw Exception on the else branch, to signal the compiler it cannot happen.

However, if you want just to ignore extra characters. you can return null on the else branch, and use`mapNotNull` to filter:

`toParse.mapNotNull { ... }.toCollection(LinkedList<Token>())`

Also, you can combine the `toCollection` and `map` calls using `mapNotNullTo`:

`toParse.mapNotNullTo(LinkedList<Token>()) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i figured it out, when has return type Any, because else branch return Unit, while other branches Token.  So intellij tries to tell me, that this is type mismatch error